# Angular directive - How to trigger a save method in the controller whenTinyMCE save button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using TinyMce angular directive for enabling Rich text editing in my angularjs application.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce

The directive works as expected. But I wanted to integrate the save plugin which will allow us to call custom save functions.
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/save/

I tried to pass a function within the angular controller as a callback function through following init option
save_onsavecallback: function () { console.log('Saved'); }

Sample code as follows (Consider that I have a very huge init object defined earlier in my application with the **save** plugin included)

```
angular.module("app").controller('editpageContentController', ['$scope', 'pagesDataService', '$routeParams', 'toaster', 'tinymceGlobalOptions',
    function ($scope, pagesDataService, $routeParams, toaster, tinymceGlobalOptions) {
        tinymceGlobalOptions.save_onsavecallback = function () { $scope.submit(); }
        $scope.tinymceOptions = tinymceGlobalOptions;
        $scope.pgContent = {
            pagePropertiesId: $routeParams.id,
            pageTitle: "",
            pageContent: ""
        }

        pagesDataService.getPageContent($scope.pgContent.pagePropertiesId).then(function (data) {
            $scope.pgContent = data;
        }, function (error) {
            toaster.pop('error', "Page load failed", error);
        });

        $scope.submit = function () {
            if ($scope.frmEditPageContent.$valid) {
                pagesDataService.savePageContent($scope.pgContent).then(function (data) {
                    if (data)
                        toaster.pop('success', "Sucess", "Page saved successfully.");
                }, function (error) {
                    toaster.pop('error', "Failure", error);
                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Not sure if I can call $scope.submit() in the callback function.. (I did try it didn't work, as well as the callback wasn't triggered at all)

I didn't see any errors logged in the Console.

Comment: When you just had `console.log('Saved');` - did it worked?

Comment: no it did not. The event wasn't triggered at all.

Comment: Here is a plnkr sample. https://plnkr.co/edit/tFCIqWTet7009kvPVdln?p=preview

Comment: I added my answer - Please accept it if it's working for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found 2 problems:

- I had to add the config `save_enablewhendirty: false,` to the default options
- I changed `data-ng-controller="testController as tc"` to `data-ng-controller="testController"` because you didn't used `controllerAs` in your app.

A working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/IbnLKsFl6YMXQxNU0RgN?p=preview

Comment: save_enablewhendirty when set to **false** works. Not sure why it didn't work when it is true. Is that a bug ? or expected result ? Thanks I always wanted to make the save button work, so that I can change my ongoing content changes from within Tiny MCE. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it's because the directive of `tiny-mce` doesn't set the field as "dirty". Maybe you need to create a `<form>`, or manually set the field as dirty (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I already  have a form tag in my actual application. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @DavidChelliah I think you're right - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/issues/210

Comment: These are the classes on textarea after the content change : **ng-untouched** ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse. ng-untouched looks wrong. I have updated my initial issue log. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/issues/260.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow that bug too and update my repository when they'll fix it